# Looking for Local Outlier Factor k-neighborhood explanation

Tags: algorithm, matplotlib, outliers, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm currently trying to understand the Local Outlier Factor algorithm and stumbled upon this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/local-outlier-factor-lof-algorithm-for-outlier-identification-8efb887d9843

This is the graph the algorithm is used on:

[image]

Later on, the article claims:
[image]

However,

creating a little python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,1,1,0]
y = [0,0,1,3]
n = ["A","B","C","D"]
from math import pi
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
list_a = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,3]])
list_b = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,3]])
ax.scatter(x, y)
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))

cir = plt.Circle((0, 3), 2, color='r',fill=False)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
ax.add_patch(cir)
plt.ylim(-3, 4)
plt.xlim(-3, 4)
plt.show()
```

results in the following image:
[image]

As you can see from this image, the radius of my circle is K=2. With this explanation:
[image]
It seems like D has no K-neighbors. But above it is stated that the K-neighbors of D are C and A.

I've also calculated the Manhattan Distance for the graph above with the following Python code:

```
list_a = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,3]])
list_b = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [1,1], [0,3]])
def get_manhattan_distance(p, q):
    distance = 0
    for p_i,q_i in zip(p,q):
        distance += abs(p_i - q_i)
    
    return distance
def run_man(list_a,list_b):
    return np.array([[get_manhattan_distance(i,j) for j in list_b] for i in list_a])
print(run_man(list_a, list_b))
```

which results into the following:

[image]

If we look at the last row of this matrix we can see that:

ManDist(D,A) = 3

ManDist(D,B) = 4

ManDist(D,C) = 3

Does the LOF algorithm only look at the the k-closest neighbors? Cause if that is the case the explanation with the circle is a little bit misleading. If it only looks at the k-closest neighbors we can see that for D -> N_2(D) = {A,C} cause they both have a Manhattan Distance of 2.

Unless my circle is incorrect I think the circle explanation is not correct?

Would be very cool if anyone who has used this algorithm before can give me some insight.
I hope it is fine to post this on stackoverflow instead of math.stackexchange.

Comment: The number of K-neighbours of every point is K, by definition. Read again more carefully.

Comment: The article states that it is a Number x >= K. Is the article wrong then? Well, if this is the case then we just use the k-closest neighbors as N_2(Point). This whole circle thing maybe just confused me.

Comment: My apologies, it can be K or more. Your statement "It seems like D has no K-neighbors" is not correct.

Comment: Alright. What do you say about the whole "circle" explanation that's stated in this article? Cause when I made my own circle with radius r=k=2 the points A and C are not in the circle.

Comment: Your circle should have radius equal to the **K-distance of D**, not radius equal to K. The K-distance of D is the distance from D to the Kth closest point to D, so for K = 2, the radius of your circle should be equal to the distance between D and A.

Comment: Damn it. I've changed it to the K-Distance of 3 and now it makes perfect sense and my circle is touching A and C aswell. While I was reading it I thought K-Distance is 2 no matter what since our K was set at 2. Thank you very much kind stranger.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @myrtlecat I've used a wrong Radius because I thought the radius of the circle must be 2. Basically I've confused K with the K-Distance.

Since the K-Distance of D is 3, we get the following picture instead:

[image]

Now everything aligns with the article and my question is answered.